# Trying to start script on EC2 deployment - /usr/bin/bundle: /usr/bin/ruby: bad interpreter error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, amazon-ec2, rvm

I want to automatically run a script when my Amazon server deploys. However, I keep getting the following error in my logs:

```
/root/start.sh: /usr/bin/bundle: /usr/bin/ruby: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
```

I've tried massaging my start script, but haven't found a solution yet. I can load the god file manually, but when I start my machine, I get the following error. **How do I set it up so that my bundler/ruby is detected when my script runs?**

`which ruby` => `/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin/ruby`

This is my script that is supposed to autorun (start.sh)

```
cat /dev/null > /root/log
echo "Starting environment for $(whoami) at $(date)" >> /root/log

export RAILS_ENV=production
export RAILS_ROOT=/root/Rails3/www_rails
export QUEUE_NAME=place_matching

export HOME=/root
[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && . "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" # Load RVM function

cd /root/Rails3/www_rails
RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec god -c /root/Rails3/www_rails/god/resque_generic.god >> /root/log 2>&1
echo "Environment running at $(date)" >> /root/log
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RVM provides documentation for your problem https://rvm.io/integration/god/

Additionally you could try this script:

```
cat /dev/null > /root/log
echo "Starting environment for $(whoami) at $(date)" >> /root/log

export RAILS_ENV=production
export RAILS_ROOT=/root/Rails3/www_rails
export QUEUE_NAME=place_matching

export HOME=/root

"$HOME/.rvm/bin/rvm" in $RAILS_ROOT do bundle exec god -c $RAILS_ROOT/god/resque_generic.god >> /root/log 2>&1
echo "Environment running at $(date)" >> /root/log
```

this is new notation of rvm which basically can be wrote down as:

```
rvm in /path/to/project do <command> ...
```

and is equivalent to what you were trying to do.

One more important thing, if you are running this as a different user thant the one owning RVM then your project `.rvmrc` requires to be trusted for that new user also. Alternatively you could use one of the new project files that do not require trusting:

- `.ruby-version` => `1.9.3@project`
- `Gemfile` => `#ruby=1.9.3@project` / `ruby="1.9.3"`
- `.versions.conf` => `ruby=1.9.3@project`

Note that the second form also does bundler validation and does not allow patchlevel nor gemset name.

Comment: thanks mpapis, I did not realize that rvm documentation covered this.